# Cannot run gunicorn with sys.argv --bind

Tags: python, gunicorn, sys, args

I am required to spin up gunicorn for an app from a python script and am trying to run `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 tito.wsgi:application`. I have tried the following:

```
import sys

    sys.argv = ['--gunicorn']

    sys.argv.append("--bind 0.0.0.0:5000")
    sys.argv.append("myapp.execute:application")


    WSGIApplication(
        usage="%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]"
    ).run()
```

This ends up with the following error:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '--bind 0'
```

If I run as:

```
sys.argv = ['--gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000']
```

It wont pick up the --bind parameter 
This works with out the `--bind` option. How to make this run with `--bind 0.0.0.0:5000` as an argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this `sys.argv.append("-b 0.0.0.0:5000")` did the trick. Seems it identified `--bind` as a module

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue with using `--bind` option or with the ipaddress `0.0.0.0`.

I take it you want to launch the application for local host. Can you try using `--bind=127.0.0.1:5000` and see if it works.